# Is it possible to use dotenv in a react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to set some environment variables (for making API calls to dev/prod endpoints, keys depending on dev/prod, etc.) and I'm wondering if using dotenv will work.

I've installed dotenv, and I am using webpack.

My webpack entry is `main.js`, so in this file I've put `require('dotenv').config()`

Then, in my webpack config, I've put this:

```
  new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin([
    'NODE_ENV',
    '__DEV_BASE_URL__'  //base url for dev api endpoints
  ])
```

However, it is still undefined.  How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The short answer is no. A browser cannot access local or server environment variables so dotenv has nothing to look for. Instead, you specify ordinary variables in your React application, usually in a settings module.

Webpack can be made to take environment variables from the build machine and bake them into your settings files. However, it works be actually replacing strings at build-time, not run-time. So each build of your application will have the values hard-coded into it. These values would then be accessible through the `process.env` object.

```
var nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV;
```

Additionally, you could use the `DefinePlugin` for webpack which lets you explicitly specify different values depending on your build target (dev, prod, etc.). Note that you have to `JSON.stringify` all values passed into it.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
}),
```

This is fine for any sort of public details but should **never be used for any sort of private keys, passwords or API secrets**. This is because any values baked in are publicly accessible and could be used maliciously if they contain sensitive details. For those sorts of things, you need to write some server-side code and build a simple API which can authenticate with the 3rd party API using the secrets, then pass the relevant details along to your client-side application. Your server-side API acts as an intermediary, protecting your secrets while still getting the data you need.

Comment: Thanks.  How can I do this for stuff like API keys?  For example, google maps API key.  I mean, that one is fine to expose I guess since only one domain origin is whitelisted.  But just curious anyway.  TY!

Comment: I've added an explanation of how to do this in my answer. The short answer is write a server-side application your client-app can talk to and do all the private/secret stuff in there.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry if this sounds dumb, but do you mean something like what I have done right now - my back end (express app) has an /api-auth endpoint which sends over a JWT which is then stored in LS.  I use that if its valid (otherwise refresh it) so that the client need to worry about getting a valid token to access any api response/data.

Comment: Sort of. You authenticate your user, but you also can use your API to proxy to other APIs. So all API requests, even ones to Google API, could be proxies through your server. The client would only care about your API and whether it was authenticated with it.

Comment: This answer should be replaced with the more popular answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 477):

*Sorry for picking up old question, but*
**react-scripts** actually uses **dotenv** library under the hood.

With react-scripts@0.2.3 and higher, you can work with environment variables this way:

1. create **.env** file in the root of the project
2. set environment variables starting with **REACT_APP_** there
3. access it by **process.env.REACT_APP_...** in components

***.env***

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

***App.js***

```
const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;
```

See [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) for more details.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, to whoever tried and didn't work right away, just restart your react app.

Comment: Another note, installing dotenv by yourself and initializing it seems to mess things up.

Comment: If we are using `nodemon` and storing values in `nodemon.js`, we have to restart the server. Nodemon auto-reload on file change will not work and values will not be stored in process.env

Comment: Is this dangerous to use for API keys, won't these variables compile and become public in production?

Comment: @ArielFrischer here is a good detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838015/using-api-keys-in-a-react-app

Comment: you did saved my time bro :)

Comment: how to set env when run locally? I mean I want to start like 'yarn start:prod' and prod env is set

Comment: @David probably you are looking for this console command: `$ NODE_ENV=production yarn start`. Does it work for your case?

Comment: Should be accepted as correct answer! Ty

Comment: @DmitryDemidovsky I tried it also but no luck. seems like default process.env.NODE_ENV unable to be redefined manually

Comment: Note: You __must__ create custom environment variables beginning with **REACT_APP_**. (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

Comment: @David if you're on a windows machine, you probably need cross-env package, as setting NODE_ENV in the script only works with UNIX machines.

Comment: unfortunately, none of the above works; after digging some info, as I understood you can not overwrite local env unless you do eject for project

Comment: To underscore Pedro Ferrari's comment, allowing webpack dev server to refresh your app after adding a .env file may not suffice. You may need, as I did, to stop and re-run `npm start`.

Comment: nandri and vanakkam

Comment: Use the following - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dotenv

Comment: why is it safer than including the strings in the code?

Answer (score 19):

Actually, you can use dotenv in your React app with webpack. Moreover, there are several ways of doing it. However, keep in mind that it's still a build-time configuration.

1. A similar way to the answer above. You import `dotenv` in your webpack config and use DefinePlugin to pass the variables to your React app. More complete guide on how you can inject your `.env` files depending on current configuration could be found [in this blog](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5).
2. Using a [`dotenv-webpack` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack). I personally find it really convenient. Let's say you have environments: `dev`, `staging` and `prod`. You create .env file for each environment (`.env.dev`, `.env.staging`, etc). In your webpack configuration you need to pick a correct file for the environment:

   ```
   const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

   module.exports = (env, argv) => {
       const envPath = env.ENVIRONMENT ? `.env.${env.ENVIRONMENT}` : '.env';

       const config = {
           ...
           plugins: [
               new Dotenv({
                   path: envPath
               })
           ]
       };

       return config;
   };
   ```

When you build the app for a particular environment, just pass the environment name to webpack:

```
webpack --config webpack.config.js --env.ENVIRONMENT=dev
```

Answer (score 19):

1. Create .env file

   ```
   API_URL=http://localhost:8000
   ```
2. Install dotenv npm package

   ```
   $ npm install --save-dev dotenv
   ```
3. Config webpack to add env variables

   ```
   const webpack = require('webpack');
   const dotenv = require('dotenv');

   module.exports = () => {
     // call dotenv and it will return an Object with a parsed key 
     const env = dotenv.config().parsed;

     // reduce it to a nice object, the same as before
     const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
       prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
       return prev;
     }, {});

     return {
       plugins: [
       new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys)
     ]
   };
   ```

Comment: And how can I use them in my service for example?

Comment: @Vladyn the same that you would normally use them: `process.env.MY_ENV_VARIABLE`

Answer (score 2):

To set up a .env file in a React project, follow these steps:

1. Create a new file named `.env` at the root of your React project.
2. Add the environment variables in the .env file in the format `VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE`. For example:

   ```
   REACT_APP_API_URL=https://api.example.com
   REACT_APP_API_KEY=YOUR_API_KEY
   ```

   Note: It is recommended to prefix your environment variables with `REACT_APP_` to ensure they are picked up by React's build process.
3. Save the .env file.
4. Restart your development server or build process to load the environment variables.

In your React components, you can access the environment variables like this:

```
const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
```

Make sure not to commit the .env file to version control systems like Git, as it might contain sensitive information like API keys and other credentials.

If you are using Create React App, it automatically picks up the variables from the .env file. However, if you are using a custom setup, you might need to configure your build tools accordingly to support .env files.

Answer (score 2):

**To use dotenv variables in a React project, Here's how you can do it using a config.js file in the src folder:**

1. *npm install dotenv --save*
2. Create **.env** file and add variable prefixed with **REACT_APP_**

```js
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:5000
```

3. Create a **config.js** file in the src folder of your project to handle environment variables.

```js
// src/config.js
export const API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
```

4. Use environment variables in your React components: Import the variables from the config.js file and use them in your components. For example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { API_URL } from './config';

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>API URL: {API_URL}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: you didn't load dotenv. How could this work?