# Environment Variables not getting set in Nodejs app

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, create-react-app

For some reason I can't set the environment variables on my node js app. I am currently trying to use dotenv package to set my environment variables and I put a log statement in the config() method to print out the processes.env variable and it looks like it adds the variables correctly. However, once I'm back in my index.js when my app runs, logging the process.env only shows the following environment variables:

```
NODE_ENV : "development"
PUBLIC_URL : ""
```

I've tried just about everything. Why can't I set the environment variables for my node app?

Comment: can you show your code on how you use dotenv package and your .env file?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ubqneJjK is my index.js file
My env file is just ENVNAME=VARIABLE

Comment: it is because you are using dotenv in a client side app. see answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182577/is-it-possible-to-use-dotenv-in-a-react-project