# How to use global configuraion in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Recently I am studying ReactJS.

I want to set a global configuration variable such as SERVER_IP_ADDR.

So, when I ask the server for an API (get / post) as Ajax,

I would like to use this global configuration variable in ReactJS.

I usually create a global variable in JavaScript,

Just import it and use it anywhere.

/js/config.js

```
var SERVER_IP_ADDR
```

/js/main.js

```
<script src="/js.config.js"></script>
```

and like this

```
<script>
  function request() {
    url = SERVER_IP_ADDR;
  }

</script>
```

Can not I set up this structure in ReactJS?

Comment: While it is possible to do what you are looking to do, I suggest you look into [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182577/is-it-possible-to-use-dotenv-in-a-react-project) on how to use dotenv environment variables in a react project. If you are using `create-react-app` then you can also check [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

Answer (score 2):

You could export a configuration object and import it wherever you need it.

js.config.js

```
const config = {
  SERVER_IP_ADDR: '...',
  OTHER_CONFIG_KEY: '...'
}

export default config;
```

and in the file you need it

```
import configuration from "./js.config"

function request(){
   fetch( configuration.SERVER_IP_ADDR );
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply. By the way, do I have to import every time I use config?

Comment: In addition, I want to create a global function ...
Is it possible to generate it in the same way as above?

Comment: @HoonyB yes. You can add anything you want in the object. Or you can export a function directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), You should use .env variables for such thing.

1. Add .env file in your root path, file content would be like this:
   REACT_APP_SERVER_IP_ADDR=http://myapi.com
   REACT_APP_CUSTOM_VARIABLE=foobar
2. then in your source code, you can use it like this:
   `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_IP_ADDR}/v1/user`

More info regarding .env: [.env](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can , you can use the config.js file and use it multiple places.

your config.js file looks like

```
module.exports={
  url : 'api.xxx.com'
}
```

and you can import it like

```
import config from './config';

config.url
```