# Env-cmd environment variables in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

I seem to have tried every which way variation of the env-cmd command but cannot work out why I can't access the variables

I originally followed this tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SH5AQsHypA

but the docs have since changed and so you need to use the command -e unlike the video so my package.json command reads...

```
"dev-server": "env-cmd -e dev webpack-dev-server",
```

any my .env-cmdrc reads...

```
{
    "dev" : {
        "BASE_URL" : "development"
    },
    "qa" : {
        "BASE_URL" : "qa"
    },
    "prod" : {
        "BASE_URL" : "prod"
    }
}
```

But I just cannot access process.env.BASE_URL for some reason. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested this far along. This was actually solved in the end by using the Dotenv-webpack library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack

in your webpack config file;

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
```

pass the parameter of env to module.exports

```
module.exports = (env) => {
 let ENV_CONFIG;

 if(env === 'dev'){
     ENV_CONFIG = new Dotenv({path: './environment/.env-dev'})
 }

 if(env === 'staging'){
     ENV_CONFIG = new Dotenv({path: './environment/.env-staging'})
 }

 if(env === 'production'){
     ENV_CONFIG = new Dotenv({path: './environment/.env-production'})
 }
}
```

then in plugins...

```
plugins : [
    ENV_CONFIG
]
```

your package.json script may then look something like..

```
"build:prod": "webpack -p --env production"
```

You should then be able to access your variables under process.env like so;

```
process.env.SERVER_URL
```

Answer (score 28):

The Create React App documentation states that you must prefix all environment variables within your .env files with REACT_APP_ for them to be available from within your code process.env.REACT_APP_.

Try

> REACT_APP_BASE_URL

instead of BASE_URL

Comment: Thanks @Joee but Yahiya recommend that and nothing. Does this work at all if the project isnt a create-react-app bootstrap?

Comment: @Ash Hogarth - Yes it should work since env-cmd is separate library it doesn't have  any dependencies on create-react-app. In face create-react-app is a boilerplate code so if some library work on it will surely work on non create-react-app project too. Hope you got my point. Thanks.

Comment: Hot dang, I'll keep plugging away! Thanks for your help though so far dude

Comment: @AshHogarth that is fine as you defined the scripts in the package.json and it is also fine as you defined the Joe variables in the .env-cmdrc, but to run the app it would be executed with this command, in your case applying to the .env-cmdrc what samples would be:
npm run dev-server

Comment: I don't believe this, I spent many hours trying to solve this. Why!!! Create React App has that restriction: all environment variables must have prefix REACT_APP_ ??? Can anyone explain this, I've deployed my stack MERN application with docker compose and I've been believed that the error was in my docker-compose or dockerfile but not. The problem is: prefix all your env variables with REACT_APP_

Answer (score 6):

You need to prefix your environment variables with `REACT_APP_`, otheriwise, the variables will be ignored to avoid collision.

The documentation says to place your `.env` file in the root directory (`/src`) yet I managed to get away with `/src/environments/.env.local` as well as `.env.staging` and `.env.production`.

I am using `env-cmd`, and my commands are like such:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f ./environments/.env.staging npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "start:naked": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "start:local": "env-cmd -f ./environments/.env.local yarn start:naked",
    "start:staging": "env-cmd -f ./environments/.env.staging yarn start:naked",
    "start:production": "env-cmd -f ./environments/.env.production yarn start:naked",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f ./environments/.env.staging npm run build",
    "build:prod": "env-cmd -f ./environments/.env.production npm run build",
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src -o dist/styles",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src -o dist/styles --watch",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

http://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: I was getting an error that env-cmd is not recognized ... it seems env-cmd is a seperate library that we need to install....  https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd

Comment: @ATHER `env-cmd` is not required for the base environment file. `react-scripts` @0.2.3 and higher use `dotenv` under the hood. I'm just additionally using `env-cmd`, `node-sass-chokidar`, and `npm-run-all` in my build process. Check out this answer for more details on `react-scripts` and `dontenv`.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182577/is-it-possible-to-use-dotenv-in-a-react-project#answer-56668716

Comment: my .env file was in the /src directory but moving it to the main source code directory solved the problem thanks

Answer (score 3):

package.json

```
"dev-server": "env-cmd dev webpack-dev-server",
```

add a prefix like

> REACT_APP_

```
{ 
  "dev" : 
      { "REACT_APP_BASE_URL" : "development" }, 
  "qa" : 
      { "REACT_APP_BASE_URL" : "qa" }, 
  "prod" : 
      { "REACT_APP_BASE_URL" : "prod" } 
}
```

rerun the project and call it using

```
process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL
```

Comment: Still nothing :(

Comment: clear cache before rerunning the project **npm cache clean --force**

Comment: You have to give it the -e flag when using an env-cmdrc file according to the env-cmd docs. Tried it without and get an 'unable to locate env file' error

Comment: is the react app prefix part of create react app? is that something seperate to regular react? That may be a silly question

Comment: @AshHogarth I think so. I am a newbie to react. you can refer here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/ .

Answer (score 2):

With `ReactJS 18.2.0` using `env-cmd` library,

> For more complex projects, a .env-cmdrc file can be defined in the
> root directory and supports as many environments as you want. Simply
> use the -e flag and provide which environments you wish to use from
> the .env-cmdrc file. Using multiple environment names will merge the
> environment variables together.

In simple, if you want the all environment declaration with similar variable keys in one file, like development, dev1, staging, test, qa, test, production, etc., so if you use `REACT_APP_API_URL` so based on the environment, it would serve you the value.

Using `env-cmd` 10.1.0 library (which has been not updated since 3 years as on date, but popular) could achieve using `.rc` file OR `.env-cmdrc`

I've used using `.env-cmdrc` (I've not used like `.env-cmdrc.json`) putting inside the project root directory, means parallel to `package.json` file.

Now let's deep inside the `.env-cmdrc`

```
{
  "development": {
    "README": "Variable Keys starting with REACT_APP_* will be visible to process.env with ReactJS 18 Scripts, like this README will not get reflect there inside app after process.env, because it won't started with REACT_APP, this is the way because project got started from create-react-app, hence this is the reason.",
    "REACT_APP_ENV": "development",
    "REACT_APP_URL": "http://localhost:3000/",
    "REACT_APP_API_URL": "https://something-a.onrender.com/thedb"
  },
  "test": {
    "REACT_APP_ENV": "test",
    "REACT_APP_URL": "http://localhost:3000/",
    "REACT_APP_API_URL": "https://something-a.onrender.com/thedb"
  },
  "production": {
    "REACT_APP_ENV": "production",
    "REACT_APP_URL": "https://somethingdb.netlify.app/",
    "REACT_APP_API_URL": "https://something-a.onrender.com/thedb"
  }
}
```

Note: Variable Keys starting with `REACT_APP_*` will be visible to `process.env` with `ReactJS` 18 Scripts, like this README will not get reflect there inside app after process.env, because it won't started with `REACT_APP`, this is the way because project got started from `create-react-app`, hence this is the reason.

Now, let's move to `package.json` file.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd --environments development react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd --environments production react-scripts build",
    "test": "env-cmd --environments test react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Now, if somewhere I want to get value variable key `REACT_APP_API_URL` based on whatever environment, simply use `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL`

the trick is that every variable must starts with `REACT_APP` and to start the project in development, I write in `vscode` terminal `npm start`

I hope it would clear many of the peoples doubt & issue.