# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in node_modules\dotenv\lib'

Tags: angular, dotenv

I'm trying to use dotenv with an angle, but when it comes to requiring dotenv

```
 require('dotenv').config()  
 or
 const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\57322\Favorites\Proyecto\core4edu\node_modules\dotenv\lib'

package.json

```
"dotenv": "^8.2.0",
"dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
```

Comment: Have you checked this answer? https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/233

Comment: yes, I tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: If you're using NextJS or React framework, you don't need to use dotenv to import the environment variables. There's now a built-in way to handle a .env file.

Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182577/is-it-possible-to-use-dotenv-in-a-react-project/56668716#56668716

Answer (score 22):

I think the problem is related to webpack, I had the same problem on a next.js project and here is how I did to fix the problem.

[image: Create file conf.js in root folder]

I created a `next.conf.js` file in my root folder where there is my `.env` file, I imported `dotenv` and I exported the module where there is all my environment and these variables as if below.

[image: export module dot env]

Finally in my index file and my components I don’t need to import `dotenv`, I just need to paste my `process.env.API_URL`.

[image: you dont need to import dotenv in index]

I hope this example solves your problem.

Comment: Did not work for me. I get `'REACT_APP_MY_ENV_VAR' is not defined.` in the `next.conf.js` file. What calls `next.conf.js`, how do I know it's being used?

Comment: Worked for me except, I had to use colon instead of =
env: {
    YB_RAILS: process.env.YB_RAILS,
  },

Comment: In NEXT JS, there is a built-in support for loading variables actually, You dont need to specifically find a loader

Comment: Thank you sir, been at this the whole day ! :D Genius ;)

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar situation - working in the webpack development mode, installing dotenv, getting an error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in node_modules\dotenv\lib'".

I uninstalled dotenv and stayed just with dotenv-webpack for development. I configured the webpack.config.js as it is written in [docs](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack/blob/master/README.md).

Everything works now. Env variables are accessible globally without creating any additional file.

Answer (score 12):

I faced a similar problem. dotenv-webpack installation will suffice. It is the dotenv require statement which is causing problem. Remove that and you will be good to go!

```js
require('dotenv').config(); // Remove this line
```

Comment: You're welcome @mitsu. Glad to see this small contribution making some difference.

Answer (score 10):

If you encounter this error with a `create-react-app` app, you need to go to the `react-scripts` webpack config.

In your `webpack.config.js` under 'resolve':

```
resolve: {
  // ...
  // add the fallback setting below 
  fallback: {
    "fs": false,
    "os": false,
    "path": false
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Editing node_modules wouldn't be the right solution if you're collaborating with others. They would still face this error on every fresh npm install

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem for myself as follows:

1. create a file next.config.js in root directory
2. which contains the following code:

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    REACT_APP_API_HOST:'http://localhost:5001',
  },
}
```

3. and after that, the variable `REACT_APP_API_HOST` became available in client part of my Next.js application as `process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST`

Answer (score 0):

This little addition to `package.json` starting from `Angular 9` (confirmed on `Angular 10`) fixes this problem.

```
...
"browser": {
  "fs": false
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to also add TypeScript code on top of [@Sidouxie's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62093786/3025856):

1. Create a file that ends with `.d.ts` in your root directory.
2. Add this to the file:

   ```
   declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
      interface ProcessEnv {
        API_URL:string;
      }
     }
   }
   ```

This will globally check your environment variables in your TypeScript project.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, this was the solution for me [enter link description here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).