# npm run build failing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-build

I am trying to build my react and node.js web app but fail to build ever since fixing packages.

i get the following error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'my-app/node_modules/dotenv/lib'


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have tried to clear the cache of node_modules, remove package-lock.json, re install with npm and re-build, but nothing works.

Does anyone know how to solve this please?

Comment: Are you using webpack ? And if so, which version ?

Comment: delete node modules and package-lock.json and then try again maybe there is some file

Comment: @Orijhins Webpack are a part of my node_modules yes

Comment: @SakshiMahajan unfortunately this doesn't work

Comment: @Joshua https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59911706/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs-in-node-modules-dotenv-lib refer this thread may be it help

Comment: Thanks @SakshiMahajan I managed to resolve it by removing dotenv completely and using the Azure config to load my env variables, but if i want to use dotenv i will use that link you sent me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Node Core Modules like fs won't work in the browser because they require binaries that aren't present in the browser. It apparently has been stubbed out of create-react-app, as per [this Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3074).

The web doesn't have a filesystem, so it makes sense it won't ever work. Unfortunately for you, it means you should find a workaround. What were you trying to achieve with fs ?

Comment: Thanks Orijhins, i never knew i was using 'fs', i never installed in and it isn't used within the project either. I added. 


"browser": {
  "fs": false,
  "path": false,
  "os": false
}
 to the package.json

But the issue still persists

Comment: You may have used an older version of create-react-app, in which case I do believe they installed fs by default. You can then just uninstall it and rebuild to check if it solved your problem.

Comment: Since you say it's installed by default, do you know which version of react I will have to use ?

Comment: You can read the doc here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started. They recommend uninstalling create-react-app and using `npx create-react-app` instead

Comment: Ok ill check it out, thanks Orijhins

Answer (score 0):

This may be a short hand fix, but i removed the dotenv package and loaded my env variables into the Azure config variables.