# Changing API endpoint between development and production (React/Django)

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack, axios, django-webpack-loader

I am developing a react app inside of a django project and connect them using the Django rest framework. For making API calls from within the react app I am using axios.

Now in my development environment, I obviously call a localhost URL to access the API. For this, I have a file that contains an axios instance:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/",
  timeout: 60000,
});
```

Obviously, my API calls don't work in production as the URL differs from the one above. I am compiling my react app to a static file which I include in my django project so I don't think I could really add any code that checks for the environment.

One idea that I had is that I could include a file into my project that I would not push into production and then check for whether this file exists or not and adjust the url in an if statement. However, I am not sure if that is a good solution or how I would implement this in plain Javascript.

I am happy to hear any thoughts on this

**Edit**

After thinking about my question, it actually doesn't make any sense - I am compiling my file before committing it so it can't be dynamic anyways. What I actually need is one main.js file which I am using in development and another one that I would use in production. However, I have no idea how I could achieve this as I am not bundling any files in production? Maybe there is a way of always bundling two files - one with the localhost url and the other one with my production url.

I am using the django-webpack-loader application which tells my django application which file to load into the html file. By accessing environment variables, I could arrange that change. But how do I tell webpack to make the two distinct bundles?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like [`dotenv`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme) to access environment variables to configure your `baseURL`.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42182577/7395911) asks if it is possible, and there are many solutions discussed there, like [using .env](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56668716/7395911) and configuring it with [webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55741007/7395911) at build time, mind that with the last one you'll require [`dotenv-webpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but after reevaluating my question, I added an edit. I am not bundling anything at or after deployment so your suggestion won't work I believe.

Comment: @PhilippK Well if you're not bundling I believe the first option might fit your case, where it will load the environment variable when ran on your production server.

Answer (score -1):

```
// separate js file
baseURL = ""
FirstEndpoint = `${baseURL}/addition/`
...etc
```

change the baseURL in production.