# How to setup the env variable for the react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, production-environment, staging

My react app is running on http://localhost:3000 and I wanted to setup the env variable for the different environment development, production, staging and local.

my react app url for different environment are(I am mocking my urls)

```
local = http://localhost:3000
development = http://react.developmet.com
production = http://react.production.com
stage = http://react.stage.com
```

looking for a solution how i can setup the env var for different environment.

Adding my approach to the same thing just wanted to know is this approach is good or not.

and how I can achieve same for staging environment

I have created an **environment.js** file.

```
let BASE_URL = http://localhost:3000

//check for environment
if (process.env.REACT_APP_ENV = "development") {
  BASE_URL = "http://react.developmet.com"
}
if (process.env.REACT_APP_ENV = "production") {
  BASE_URL = "http://react.production.com"
}

export {BASE_URL}
```

and also updated my run scripts

```
"scripts": {
     "dev":"REACT_APP_ENV=development npm start",
     "prod":"REACT_APP_ENV=productionnpm start",
     "build:dev":"REACT_APP_ENV=development npm run-script build",
     "build:prod":"REACT_APP_ENV=production npm run-script build",
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182577/is-it-possible-to-use-dotenv-in-a-react-project

Answer (score 4):

You can use [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) to manage your build for multiple `env` files:

#### Installation:

```
yarn add env-cmd -D
```

#### Create env files

1. Create a folder `envs` at root project level
2. Create `.env` files *(as many as you need)*

e.g. `envs/.env.dev`, `envs/.env.prod`, `envs/.env.staging` etc

#### A Sample .env (e.g. `envs/.env.prod`) file

```
REACT_APP_API_HOST=http://my-prod-api.example.com
REACT_APP_ANY_OTHER_VAR=some_value
```

#### Configure scripts in package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "env-cmd -f envs/.env.dev react-scripts build",
    "prod": "env-cmd -f envs/.env.prod react-scripts build",
    "staging": "env-cmd -f envs/.env.staging react-scripts build",
  },
```

#### Make the build:

```
$ yarn dev // to make build for dev env
$ yarn prod // to make build for prod env
$ yarn staging // to make build for staging env
```

PS: You can use `npm` commands as well. I used `yarn` only for example purpose.

Comment: inside .env.dev file do i need to pass url like REACT_APP_DEV = http://react.developmet.com ?

Comment: Yes, please check my updated answer. I added a sample `.env` file. You can put your env vars in the file.

Comment: when i am making a build for dev usnig npm run build:dev this is returning me the production enviroment(in the porcess.env,.NODE_ENV) so, i am getting my dev url as undefined when i am consoling it