# What is best way to handle .env api urls, based on enviroments (dev / prod) REACT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

Here is the way in which I set up different API URL based on the current environment:

Development and Production, on npm, commanded setup env.

Is there are some more elegant solution cus my URLs are long:

Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://test-dev-1323211.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/3.0 react-scripts start",
    "build": "REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://test-1323211.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/3.0 react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prepare": "husky install",
 
  },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Detecting production vs. development React at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469836/detecting-production-vs-development-react-at-runtime)

Comment: [How to setup the env variable for the react app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66365372/2873538)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .env files using dotenv library.
See: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

EDIT:

## From the docs

### Adding Development Environment Variables In .env

To define permanent environment variables, create a file called .env in the root of your project:

`REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE=abcdef`

> Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require you to restart the development server if it is running.

---

You can read more at the CRA docs or at DotEnv docs.

## Solution

Basically you can use .env and .env.development.local to separate the URLs.

.env:

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://test-1323211.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/3.0
```

.env.development.local:

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://test-dev-1323211.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/3.0
```

Comment: Linking elsewhere is not a sufficient answer; if you are sure this question isn't a duplicate, please include the relevant information in your answer.