# Cannot reach key from .env file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dotenv

I'm on React.Js and using emailjs to manage contact form. In order to sends the form, I must fill the user-id and template-id. But I don't want it to be visible so I put it on the .env file like that:

```
REACT_APP_USER_ID= user_id
REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID= template_id
```

To pass these values easely in the sendForm() property, I've put them on variables :
(useContact.jsx)

```
const template = REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID
const user = REACT_APP_USER_ID
```

But unfortunately with this config the form is not sent.

my folder architecture
[.env, package.json, .gitignore, src/Components/Contact/useContact.jsx]

It works when pass the raw version of the values.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Env variables are accessible through `process.env`

It depends how are you loading your .env file, I would suggest you to take a look at [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) in order to load your env files

An example you could follow it's the one from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63021138/8097791)

Answer (score 4):

You can access the environment variables by accessing process.env variable like this

```
const template = process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID
const user = process.env.REACT_APP_USER_ID
```

Note: you have to restart the server after updating .env file