# import from a directory outside the current package

Tags: reactjs, node.js, vite, dotenv

I have a server and a client folder with their own package.json as per:

```
home
├── server
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
│        └── constants.js
└── client
    ├── package.json
    └── src
         └── index.js
```

I am trying to import some constants from my server package into my React client

##### server/src/constants.js

```
export const test = 'hello'
```

##### client/src/index.js

```
import { test } from '../../server/src/constants.js'
```

How can I do this without errors?

I'm not sure what it's doing at the moment as it appears to be picking up the `.env` file, I get this in the browser console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
> at ../server/node_modules/dotenv/lib/env-options.js

Maybe this isn't the best way of doing it? I could pass it via an API call, but I'm trying to keep it simple, and not rely on the API (for reasons of version checking etc)...

EDIT: I guess the issue seems to be that it's invoking dotenv, as soon as it crosses the root of 'server'. And that's throwing an error because it doesn't compile for react. So maybe the problem is dotenv, and how to disable that for files outside of its root?

Comment: Do you need to browserify the `process` module in your webpack or provide an environment variable?  See: [Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30239060/1563833)

Comment: This looks along the right track... although I don't need any env vars really, and I'm not sure why it's trying to use them. All I'm doing is importing from my constants file.

Comment: Why are you trying to use dotenv in a browser project at all?  There is no way to get environment variables on that platform.  I suppose you could have access to your build system's environment variables during the webpack step.  Also, maybe you should read [Is it possible to use dotenv in a react project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182577/is-it-possible-to-use-dotenv-in-a-react-project)

Comment: I'm NOT trying to use dotenv. That's the whole point! I'm trying to import a file, that's all. It happens to reside in the 'server' directory, as it's a file needed by both server and client. And for some reason it's invoking dotenv, which I definitely do not want it to do!

Comment: I suppose you could start by doing `npm list --all` to see which module in the client depends on dotenv.  Then you may be able to figure out how dotenv got there (presumably inadvertently), and consider what it would take to remove it.  Does your client depend on any *other* submodules shared with the server?  Perhaps you have some **other** server-side code polluting your client?

Comment: I think I'd have to see your client/package.json to reproduce the problem (mostly to see how it's being bundled).  Can you add a minimal client/package.json to your example that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your message has all the clues you need with `../server` which says go up one folder/directory then find the `node_modules` but as you see in your diagram it is not there.

You need `../../../server` or just a simple `/server` from the root.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. There is a node_modules in both client and server, I've just left  them out as they're not part of this - I'm not trying to import environment variables between the two, just what's in constants.js

Comment: The path is definitely correct. I can nav to it by CMD+click from calling file

Comment: Perhaps the error message is more a different issue and is more a distraction; kind of hard to tell without more details.

Comment: I guess the issue seems to be that it's invoking dotenv, as soon as it crosses the root of 'server'. And that's throwing an error because it doesn't compile for react. So maybe the problem is dotenv, and how to disable that for files outside of its root?

Comment: I would not consider myself enough of an expert in this combination of these 4 tech in combination with routing to offer an effective/better answer; I wish I was better help here.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your time anyway